# Help with this proof of a sucession limits

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let k be a given real number. Proof that a sucession $(a_n)$ converges to $r$ is given $\varepsilon>0$ exists a natural $x$ such that $|an - r|< k\cdot\varepsilon$ for any  $n \ge x$.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I dont know where to start

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We *know that* given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $x$ such that if $n > x$ then $|a_n-r| < k\epsilon$.

Now, we'll do something very simple: replace $\epsilon$ in the above statement by $\dfrac{\delta}{k}$, which is a fixed quantity because $k$ is a constant.
Now the above statement becomes:

> We *know that* given $\frac{\delta}{k} > 0$, there is a natural number $x$ such that if $n > x$ then $|a_n-r| < k\frac{\delta}{k} = \delta$.

Note that if $\frac{\delta}{k} > 0$ of and only if $\delta>0$. Hence, the following statement is also true:

> We *know that* given $\delta > 0$, there is a natural number $x$ such that if $n > x$ then $|a_n-r| < k\frac{\delta}{k} = \delta$.

This is the definition of convergence that we know. Hence the two definitions are the same. All it takes is some rewriting and variable naming.